# How can I clean a file descriptor after writing into a file with dup2()?

Tags: c, process, locking, fork, ipc

I would like to write a program that writes argument passed by terminal on two files named (fichier, copie).

**First**, same order of arguments in both files, as well order provided in terminal using a child process for each argument.

**Secondly**, same order of arguments in both files eventhough it will be different from the order of arguments provided in terminal.

I have written the code below using "locking" in order to write each argument in both files (fichier, copie), but it seems that I cannot get the arguments written in both files. I get all the arguments written in the second file (copie) due to dup2() function (I think I have an issue with file descriptor).

I would be very glad if someone could explain to me how can I clear the file descriptors and get the arguments written in both files.

***Command:***  ./try hello haha hene

***Output:*** in the "copie" file, but the "fichier" file is empty

1. 88961 a ecrit haha
2. 88961 a ecrit haha
3. 88962 a ecrit hene
4. 88962 a ecrit hene
5. 88960 a ecrit hello
6. 88960 a ecrit hello

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void fils(char *chaine){
    int fic1 = open("fichier", O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    lseek(fic1 ,0 ,SEEK_SET);
    lockf(fic1 ,F_LOCK,0);
    dup2(fic1, 1);

    printf("%d a ecrit %s\n",getpid(),chaine);
    lseek(fic1 ,0 ,SEEK_SET);
    lockf(fic1 ,F_ULOCK,0);

    int fic2 = open("copie", O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    lseek(fic2 ,0 ,SEEK_SET);
    lockf(fic2 ,F_LOCK,0);
    dup2(fic2, 1);
    printf("%d a ecrit %s\n",getpid(),chaine);

    int attente=rand()%2;
    fprintf(stderr,"%d attente de %d dans fichier et copie\n",getpid(),attente);
    sleep(attente);

    lseek(fic2 ,0 ,SEEK_SET);
    lockf(fic2 ,F_ULOCK,0);
    close(fic1);
    close(fic2);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    system("rm -f fichier copie");

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
        if((pid=fork())<0){
            printf("Erreur fork\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else if(pid==0){
            fils(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you're asking but I think you have a complete misunderstanding of what the `dup2` function does. It does not seem useful at all for your problem.

Comment: I also don't understand what you think `lockf` does here.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is written to `fichier` because you don't use `fflush(stdout)` and the buffer is not full before you switch standard output to write to `copie`.

The `lseek()` calls are mostly pointless; the writing will occur at the end of the file because of `O_APPEND`.  The logic behind them is to ensure that the whole file is locked, but …

The `lockf()` calls are pointless; the `O_APPEND` flag ensures that writing takes place at the end of the file, and the contents of separate concurrent write calls in separate processes are not interleaved for disk files.

Putting this together, along with a loop to wait for the child processes to die, leads to:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void fils(char *chaine)
{
    int fic1 = open("fichier", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fic1, 1);
    close(fic1);

    printf("%d a ecrit %s\n", (int)getpid(), chaine);
    fflush(stdout);

    int fic2 = open("copie", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    dup2(fic2, 1);
    close(fic2);
    printf("%d a ecrit %s\n", (int)getpid(), chaine);
    fflush(stdout);

    int attente = rand() % 2;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d attente de %d dans fichier et copie\n", (int)getpid(), attente);
    sleep(attente);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    pid_t pid;

    remove("fichier");
    remove("copie");

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Erreur fork\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            fils(argv[i]);
        }
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
               (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I ran that, I got the output:

```
$ open29 hello haha hene
95396 attente de 1 dans fichier et copie
95395 attente de 1 dans fichier et copie
95397 attente de 1 dans fichier et copie
95394: child 95397 exited with status 0x0000
95394: child 95396 exited with status 0x0000
95394: child 95395 exited with status 0x0000
$ cat fichier
95395 a ecrit hello
95396 a ecrit haha
95397 a ecrit hene
$ cat copie
95396 a ecrit haha
95395 a ecrit hello
95397 a ecrit hene
$
```

Note that the children all slept for the same amount of time.  It takes care in seeding with `srand()` to have different sequences in the different children (for example, call `srand(getpid())` in each child, at the top of `fils()`).

I did also run a version of your code retaining your locking scheme but with `fflush(stdout)` after the calls to `printf()`.  The output was not materially different.  The file `fichier` contained lines with `hello`, `hene`, `haha`; the file `copie` contained lines with `hello`, `haha`, `hene`.  The key change is the use of `fflush(stdout);` to get the data written to `fichier` as well as `copie`.